# Energy levels of atoms

Tags: solid-state-physics, atoms, molecules

It is said when atoms bond together to become molecule their energy levels merge and split, resulting in splitting of spectral lines in molecular spectra. Why? Plz explain in layman term

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Energy levels of atoms](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/616838/energy-levels-of-atoms)

Comment: Hello! You seem to have accidentally posted the [same question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/616838/energy-levels-of-atoms) twice. Please delete one of them. Thanks!

Comment: This layman friendly post of mine on molecular bonds is worth reading: http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=62973&page=10#pid419076